# Given a specefic set $ A$ we need to find $A^\perp$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a set of functions which are an element of $L^2[0,1]$ where if we let f(x) be the function equal to 0 from $0<x<1/2$. If this set A is a subset of the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$ then we need to find $A^\perp$.

What my attempt was that we know all functions in this space will be orthogonal to f(x) = 0 from $0<x<1/2$ so if g(x) is a element of A perp, then g(x) can be any function from $0<x<1/2$. However, from the interval from $1/2<x<1$ f(x) does not have any restrictions, we would need:

$(f,g) = \int_{1/2}^1 f\bar g = 0$, then we need to find g such that this is true, that's where I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's study the restriction of $A$ on $x\in [1/2,1]$. Clearly, $A\big|_{x\in [1/2,1]}=L^2([1/2,1])$, hence $\left(A\big|_{x\in [1/2,1]}\right)^\bot=\{0\}$.

Second, as you already mentioned, if $g\in A^\bot$, then $g\big|_{x\in[0,1/2]}$ can be any function in $L^2([0,1/2])$, so we can conclude that $A^\bot=\{g\in L([0,1]):g|_{x\in[1/2,1]}=0\}$.

Comment: This what I was thinking as well. That g(x) = 0 when 
$1/2 <x < 1$, that would definitely work, thanks for confirming. I thought maybe the answer is more complicated where g depends on what f is.